# What's the purpose of ",)" in python / scripts?

Tags: python, tuples, wildcard

I have a simple question. I saw so many times that my teammates use `,)` like in a tuple (Python, bash scripts, etc.)

Example:

`animals = ("Parrot",)`

What's the purpose of this? Is it like a wildcard?

Comment: That *is* a tuple, that happens to be the way to write a tuple with only one element.

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the way to create a `tuple` containing just one element, the string "Parrot".  Without the comma, you'll end up with the string "Parrot" and no tuple.  It wouldn't be good to cause `("Parrot")` to create a `tuple`, because you ought to be able to put a pair of parentheses around any expression without changing its meaning.  The comma is needed to make it clear that you want to create a `tuple`.

As @Cyrus suggests, see the documentation for `tuples`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple